# Sitecore instance showing incorrect workflow state in Page Editor

Tags: sitecore

On our test CM server in content editor, I click Lock and Edit, which moves the page item out of the final workflow state and moves it to the first (in our case "Draft"). I then click Publish > Page Editor. In the Page Editor window, the blue workflow bar, shows the page as still being in the final workflow state. If I make a change to the page in Page Editor and press save, a new version is created...every time I save a new version is created. Back in Content Editor, it still shows as being in Draft. If I login as Admin and look at the workflow fields, it shows as in Draft.

This is only happening in our test CM server. Everything works as expected in our dev environments. To make it even more fun, it appears to not happen everytime...still can't nail down the pattern on when it does work.

Anyone know what could be causing this? It's kinda ruining my day.

I'll also add that I've compared all config files between servers and aside from connection strings, they are identical. I've also checked workflow permissions and those are identical as well.

**UPDATE**: I've figured out what was causing this behavior, but it opens up a bigger question. What's happening is that time in the Experience tab determines what you see in Page Editor. So, for the pages I was testing, the "version" I was seeing in Content Editor is not the same one I'm seeing Page Editor. The Date on the Experience tab is set to a date prior to the Publishing Restriction which was set when the new version was created.

What is the expected experience of an author in relation to the Date field on the Experience tab? If I set that date, then the date I set it to sticks there forever. If I come back to that page tomorrow, it will still have the last date which was set. This means that authors need to be constantly, manually changing that date to keep it current, which is not a great experience. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, are the standard values setup correctly? -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127005/annoying-issue-with-sitecore-workflows-and-standard-value-inheritance

Comment: yes, and editing the item and moving it through workflow in Content Editor works as expected. It's only in Page Editor that it does this.